# cURL post to server resulting in a UnknownFormat error

Tags: json, curl, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new at rails and having a hard time doing a cURL post to my server. Any help would be apreciated.

I am posting JSON data to my server. 
this is my curl post `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"photo":[{ "location": "location", "userID": "userid" },{ "location": "location", "userID": "userid" },{"location": "location", "userID": "userid"}]}]' http://localhost:3000/photo/create`

this is my controller:

```
class SendphotoController < ApplicationController

    def create
    @photo = Photo.new(:photo => params[:location], :photo => params[:userID])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @photo.save
            puts "Done"
        else
            puts "NOPE"
        end 
    end     
end
```

I get the error of `ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):`

This is the full log:

```
Started POST "/photo/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-08 22:03:56 -0400
Processing by SendphotoController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"_json"=>[{"photo"=>[{"location"=>"location", "userID"=>"userid"}, {"location"=>"location", "userID"=>"userid"}, {"location"=>"location", "userID"=>"userid"}]}], "sendphoto"=>{"_json"=>[{"photo"=>[{"location"=>"location", "userID"=>"userid"}, {"location"=>"location", "userID"=>"userid"}, {"location"=>"location", "userID"=>"userid"}]}]}}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Photo: photo
    app/controllers/sendphoto_controller.rb:4:in `create'
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "photos" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 09 Sep 2013 02:03:56 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Mon, 09 Sep 2013 02:03:56 UTC +00:00]]
   (215.8ms)  commit transaction
Done
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 235ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/sendphoto_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using a `respond_to` block, but not any formats. Your block should look something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    # respond to a web form with HTML
  }

  format.json {
    # respond to API request
  }
end
```

If you just want a generic response for all formats, you can drop the `respond_to` bit altogether. **But** `puts` isn't going to work in a Controller context (or pretty much anywhere in Rails for that matter); you have to [`render`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) something.

That might look something like this

```
def create
  if Photo.create # ...
    render text: "done"
  else
    render text: "nope"
  end
end
```